# Custom Tiny Linux LiveCD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, iso-image, livecd

I need a very small custrom made distribution that I can use to boot my system (add to boot options of an Ubuntu CD) that will mount the filesystem on disk and make some changes to it (install packages, copy files etc.)

I can modify the existing debian-installer image on ubuntu ISO by extracting, modifiying it and making a new archive, but I believe it is not the way. Since it will sit on the normal Ubuntu ISO, it needs to be very small. So options like [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/) are not fit for me. I have been looking into Damn Small Linux, but I also modify the normal ubuntu installation and I have no idea to make the both available to boot in the menu.

What is the common way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Does it have to be a standard Ubuntu CD? The way I would probably do this is by creating a CD image with Grub2, and adding the Ubuntu ISO and small Linux ISO (DSL or SliTaz if you want something even smaller) to that. Then you can use Grub2's loop-booting-feature to boot the ISO images directly.

Comment: Put a custom static build of busybox in an initrd.gz and add a boot entry.

Comment: @user55325 It does not have to be Ubuntu CD, it just needs to be able to boot my custom installation and my custom little distro.